# Modifying a video stream in real time

Tags: c++

I need to access the pixel data from a video camera attached to my Windows PC in real time.  Once accessed, I will modify it and output it as part of the video stream.  In other words, I need to find the easiest way to modify a video stream in real time.  I know about OpenCV and Matlab functionality, but I am wondering if anyone has found a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with C++, OpenCV, as long as it works with your camera, is one of the simplest ways there is. The code below is from the OpenCV documentation [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture). The only trick is instantiating the `VideoCapture` instance. How much simpler can it be?

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

There is even a python version at [Capture Video from Camera](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera) that looks very similar to the C++ version above.

Comment: Really nice example! Hint for anybody trying to build it to see it in action, the libs you need for linking are: `opencv_core`, `opencv_highgui`, `opencv_imgproc`